# Posting a JSON array to PHP

Tags: php, android, arrays, json

I'm trying to send a `JSONArray` to my server where my PHP script will take the values and search my database for matches but I can't get it to send. I keep getting a `JSONException`

> "Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value  of type
>   java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"

If I do a vardump on the server side it shows up null.

I have an array like shown:

```
ArrayList myList:
  ["BoUsQJP", "ldT6brS", "iVRuJvmP"]
```

I'm using the following code to create an object and send to my JSON parser. I'm using the "tag" for the php script server side to process it.

```
public JSONObject checkInList(ArrayList<String> myList) {
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", checkinlist_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("refids", myList.toString()));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONCheckList(checkinlistURL, params);
    System.out.println("Show me....." + params);
    return json;
}
```

JSON Parser Code:

```
public JSONObject getJSONCheckList(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "utf-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What's your json looks like? also as far as I know, json has no `\n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off for the error, you do not have a JSONObject, you have a JSONArray. The type in the array is String. So you need to parse it as an json array of strings. Or you could just get he string, trim off the opening and closing brackets "[]" and then trim the white space. Now separate based on commas.

OK, I would recommend something like this

```
@Override
    protected List<T> doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        try
        {
            if (httpClient == null)
                httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
            final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "FAILED STATUS");
                Log.d(TAG, "reason: " + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase() + ", code: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                Log.d(TAG, "attempted url: " + request.getURI().toString());
                return null;
            }
            InputStream contentInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
            String data = IOUtils.toString(contentInputStream);
            Log.d(TAG, "array json = " + data);
            data = data.toString();
            List<T> listOfT = Json.getGson().fromJson(data, type);
            return listOfT;

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e)
        {
            Log.d("TAG", "ClientProtocolException", e);
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.d("TAG", "IOException", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Because you are looking for a list of strings you would change the json line to this

```
List<String> list = Json.getGson().fromJson(data, new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType());
```

You will need the Gson jar and I think the apache jar for the IOUtils.

If you dont want to use Gson, then fear not, everything you need should be in the string `data`.

Also ignore the generics if you want, this is just a sub piece of a large versatile and easy library I made for myself since I do so many apps. Also if you want to accept more status' then just 200 OK, include them in the if conditions.

Another thing, it is an easy matter to just do this

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
jObj.put("key", "value");
```

it is also easy with the above code to create a JSONArray or JSONObject like this

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(data);
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, there must be some mistake in your PHP script.
Did you check your log ? there is something unusual ? if I guess right. json must be not right as it should be.

```
   Log.e("JSON", json);
```